# How much can I draw from the output of a flip flop?

Tags: integrated-circuit, components, flipflop

I have a simple question.  I'm looking at using http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4013b.pdf for my project and I need to be able to draw ~500ma from the 'Q' or '!Q' pin on the flipflop.  How much current can I draw?  I looked at the datasheet and couldn't find that information.

Comment: *"How much can I draw from the output of a flip flop?"* However much the datasheet says you can draw.  This *really* should have been obvious.  -1 for the dumb question.

Comment: You should also indicate what kind of load you have. If it is an inductive load (solenoid, motor, ...), there needs to be some protection.

Comment: @ti_chris Looks like you'll need an amplifier then, or a switch that can handle that kind of current

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at page 6 of the datasheet. The values for different V_o are in the range < 3..4 mA. So you have  to take a nmost or pmos switch!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9QdjD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>